# DateTime parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am writing a syslog server that receives syslog messages and stores them in a database.

I am trying to parse the date string received in the message into a `DateTime` structure.

For the following examples, I'll be using an underscore in place of whitespace for clarity; the actual strings received have spaces.

The string I received is in the format `"Jun__7_08:09:10"` - please note the two whitespaces between the month and day.

If the day is after the 10th, the strings become `"Jun_10_08:09:10"` (one whitespace).

If I parse with:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Log.Date, "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it works for strings from the 1st to 9th but throws exception from the 10th forward, and if I parse with one space, it throws an exception on the 1st to 9th (and works from the 10th on).

What is the correct way to parse this string?

Comment: As I can recall, the ParseExact can have multiple format provided instead of one, you can try to provide both below 1 digit and 2 digit format. But there may exists some format like `MMM dd HH:mm:ss` (place d instead of whitespace), but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using `d` instead of `dd`?

Comment: @Quatroking Because the day-of-the-month part doesn't have a leading zero.

Comment: Derp, of course, that's the input. Nevermind, move on!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Consider using this line:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Log.Date,
    "MMM d HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

Notice that I removed one of the spaces between the month and the day. That's because `AllowWhiteSpaces` literally means:

> Specifies that s may contain leading, inner, and trailing white spaces not defined by format.

Comment: Maybe just `AllowInnerWhite` to be more specific, but +1, I didn't even know about these options until now :)

Comment: +1 - show me I should look at the `DateTimeStyles` more carefully :)

Comment: @Rawling, yeah `AllowInnerWhite` would probably work well here too.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - it does (tested on LINQPad)

Comment: @Oded, thanks a lot! You reminded me about the multiple formats! Iron sharpen iron -that's what it's all about. And you know, that's why I love the Sportsmanship badge, there is always more than one way to get the job done.

Comment: I don't want to fix this since I don't know C# (and for all I know, the API has the typo), but shouldn't the code be `AllowWhiteSpaces`?  (instead of `Wite`?)

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) overload that takes an array of format strings:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Log.Date, 
                    new [] {"MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM d HH:mm:ss"}, 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: That overload needs a DateTimeStyles parameter as well.

Comment: @Tory - True. You mean like the one that is in my example?

Comment: Yes, exactly like the one that wasn't in your example when I commented on it. ;P

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the extra space first and then parse the string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Log.Date.Replace("  ", " "), "MMM d HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It's not pretty and fairly inflexible but it would do the job

Answer (score 1):

DateTime's [ParseExect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method has some overloads where you can pass multiple format that could be readed if the earlier one is not working. here a sample for you..

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                         "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                         "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                         "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                         "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
      string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                              "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                              "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00"}; 
      DateTime dateValue;

      foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
      {
         try {
            dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                                            new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                            DateTimeStyles.None);
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
         }
         catch (FormatException) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
         }                                               
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Converted '5/1/2009 6:32 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 PM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:05 PM.
//       Converted '5/1/2009 6:32:00' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 PM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32:00' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMM d HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite)
```