# Regular Expression for Multiple Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have three textboxes,

1st for `Date Of Birth`

2nd For `Date of Joining`

3rd for `Date of Leaving`

I want a regular expression in such a way that it should be proper validated. For ex: The date of birth should be less than the date of joining and date of leaving.

Also, the Date of Leaving should always be greater than Date of Joining. Do let me know how to validate this properly

Comment: First can you tell us, what you have tried so far?

Comment: Regular expression doesn't seem to be a right tool for the job. Parse the dates into `DateTime` and compare.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Can you please explain how to parse it ? I have no Idea about it.

Comment: There are many questions in SO, on parsing a DateTime 

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984946/datetime-parsing

Comment: You're writing asp.net application and you don't know how to parse a date in .NET? Sorry, but you should start with basic C# tutorial before you take on asp.net.

Comment: Ok, will try and find a solution. :) anyways Thanks. :)

Comment: What is the separator(e.g, '-', '/', etc.) used in dates? Why don't you use dateTimePicker control?

Comment: @L16H7: The separator is `-` and I m using datepicker only

Comment: @Nadeem Then take datetimes and directly check it with '>' or '<' operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use client side validation bu using JavaScript

tbStartDateID and tbEndDateID is the textbox controls' id where entered start date and end date respectively.

JavaScript Function:

```
function CompareDates(tbStartDateID, tbEndDateID) {
    var startDate = document.getElementById(tbStartDateID).value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById(tbEndDateID).value;
    //Difference in milliseconds
    var timeDiff =  Date.parse(endDate) - Date.parse(startDate);
    if (Date.parse(endDate) > Date.parse(startDate)) {

        alert("It is okay, end date is greater than start date");
    }
    else {
        alert("Start Date must be lesser than end Date");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### It's impossible

Date validation is basically impossible to do with regular expressions alone, 29th of February being one of the harder problems. date comparison is even harder in regex.

*find another way to do this*.

Comment: So, is there not anyway to validate this atleast to some extension.

Comment: there's no practical way to use regular expressions as full validation for dates. for splitting dates into parts they work just fine. but then you need to use something else to validate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You cannot use Regular Expressions for validating dates. 
Instead you can use something like this : 


    **HTML :**

        <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" runat="server" />
        <input type="date" id="joinDate" name="jDate" runat="server" />

    **C# Code :**

        protected Boolean Validate_DateOfBirth()
                {
                    int dateDOB, joiningDt;
                    string joiningDate = joinDate.Value; ;
                    string varDOB = dob.Value;
                    varDOB = varDOB.Replace(@"-", "");//Our string will be in yyyyMMdd format now.
                    joiningDate = joiningDate.Replace(@"-", "");

                    dateDOB=int.Parse(varDOB);
                    joiningDt = int.Parse(joiningDate);
                    if (dateDOB > joiningDt){
                        //Raise your error here. 
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        //Everything id fine..
                        return true;
                    }
                }

    You can implement the similar thing for comparing date of joining and 
date of leaving..
```